# is it ok to pass asynchronous function as Websocket(ws) listerner ? (node.js and ws library)

Tags: node.js, express, ws

the most of the actions that my websockets have to do are asycnrhonous, so I'm passing an asynchronous function as callback to the websocket and calling await inside it, is it ok to do so ? if not what alternative do I have ?
EDIT : here is my message listener :

```
ws.on('message', async function (message) {
        if (message instanceof Buffer) {
          if (currentMode == prot.dataMode) {
            await appendData(sessionData,message);
          }
          else {
            console.log("error : unexpected message received");
          }
        }
        // if the message is for defining the mode of communication
        //This message is a configuration message
        else {
          message = JSON.parse(message);
          if (message[prot.modeField] == prot.confMode) {
            console.log("conf mode");
            currentMode = prot.confMode;
            await configure(sessionData,message);
          }
          //The following messages will be data
          else if (message[prot.modeField] == prot.dataMode) {
            console.log("data mode");
            currentMode = prot.dataMode;
          }

          else{
            console.log("unknown message structure : ");
            console.log(message);
          }
        }

      });
```

Comment: Can you edit some example code into your question? Is there any chance of any Promise rejecting?

Comment: there is a very tiny chance for that, but let's say there isn't, is it okey to do so ? I have added the code, I hope it is clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is *no* chance of any of the Promises rejecting, then yes, using an `async` function as the handler is OK. Your current approach will work.

But this is unrealistic. The callback handler doesn't *expect* an `async` function, and if the Promise generated by it rejects, then you'll get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` - a rejected Promise was created, which wasn't handled anywhere. This is *ugly* - unhandled Promise rejections are deprecated, and in the future they will *crash your process*, which you *definitely* don't want.

If you use an `async` function, then make sure to `try/catch` everything you `await` inside, because otherwise, if anything awaited rejects, the whole function will return a rejected Promise, resulting in the above problems. For example:

```
ws.on('message', async function (message) {
  if (message instanceof Buffer) {
    if (currentMode == prot.dataMode) {
      try {
        await appendData(sessionData,message);
      } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error', e);
      }
    }
    else {
      console.log("error : unexpected message received");
    }
  }
  // if the message is for defining the mode of communication
  //This message is a configuration message
  else {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    if (message[prot.modeField] == prot.confMode) {
      console.log("conf mode");
      currentMode = prot.confMode;
      try  {
        await configure(sessionData,message);
      } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error', e);
      }
    }
    //The following messages will be data
    else if (message[prot.modeField] == prot.dataMode) {
      console.log("data mode");
      currentMode = prot.dataMode;
    }

    else{
      console.log("unknown message structure : ");
      console.log(message);
    }
  }
});
```

All that said, while the above code *technically* fulfills your requirements, it's a bit odd, because you're waiting for Promises, but not doing anything after waiting for them. `await` is syntax sugar for `.then`, but if you don't have any logic you need to perform in the `.then` (such as after an `await`, or at the consumer of the `async` function here), it's strange to have `await` at all, you may as well just `.catch` the Promises, and leave out the `async` and `try` parts entirely, eg:

```
if (currentMode == prot.dataMode) {
  appendData(sessionData,message)
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('Error', e);
    });
```

If you *also* want to make sure `appendData` will only run after the last `appendData` call is completed, use a Promise queue, perhaps something like:

```
const appendDataQueue = [];
function queueAppend(sessionData, message) {
  appendDataQueue.push({ sessionData, message });
  tryRunNext();
}
let active = false;
function tryRunNext() {
  if (active || !appendDataQueue.length) {
    return;
  }
  const { sessionData, message } = appendDataQueue.unshift();
  active = true;
  appendData(sessionData, message)
    .then(() => {
      active = false;
      tryRunNext();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // handle errors
      active = false;
      tryRunNext();
    });
}
```

And then, in the `.on` handler, call `queueAppend` instead of calling `appendData` (and, again, no need for an `async` function):

```
if (currentMode == prot.dataMode) {
  queueAppend(sessionData,message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the objective of using await is to make sure that appendData finishs before another appendData is called.

Comment: Should have said that initially - see edit, use a Promise queue

Comment: Never heard of this before, thanks a lot, one last question, since their will be multiple socket, where should I declare the queue to have a different queue for each socket ? inside the on("connection") ?

Comment: You should declare the queue outside of it, so that all sockets can access the same queue.

Comment: no each socket is writing to a different "blob" (azure storage)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about how ws is handling the sockets, is it a thread per socket ? cause I have been told that nodeJs is single threaded in general

Comment: Yes, it's single-threaded - if an event occurs while another event is being processed, that second event will only run once the first event's processing has completed, once the interpreter has finished with the current event loop queue.

Comment: ok that's a little bit weird for a server that is supposed to handle a lot of concurrent requests/websockets... thank you !

Comment: fyi: try-await-catch is syntactic suger for .then().catch(). So there is nothing weird using one or the other. For people who are from other languages like c# , the try await style is much more readable and modern. C# has someting equivalent to then().catch() too but it is rarely used nowadays. So I personally would rather go full try-await-catch instead of chaining then().catch() in this case. Those are eventHandlers, so they are fire-and-forget anyway.