# Processing order of websocket data is incorrect

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, async-await

The output order is incorrect and at times test_1 and test_2 are undefined at the time of calling console.log

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises
const wss = newWebSocket(some_url)

// payload sent to websocket successfully using wss.send()


// message recieved from server
wss.on('message',async function (msg){
    console.log(msg)
    var test_1 = await fsp.readFile (file,'utf-8')
    console.log(test_1)

    var test_2 = await func_1 (test_1, args)
    console.log(test_2)
});
```

Most likely this is because the time taken for processing the messages is longer than the time taken for transmitting new messages by the server. If it helps, I am accessing Bitfinex websocket API. Based on what I have read, it seems that storing incoming messages in a queue may help. However I am clueless about how to implement this. I would appreciate it someone could explain the solution in a simple and detailed manner - I am new to working with Javascript and still trying to wrap my head around its asynchronous nature.

I have looked at several answers to similar questions but feel that they are too complicated for a novice like me.

Any help would be appreciated. I am completely clueless here

Comment: your code sample contains syntax errors: Missing closing `)` from `wss.on(` . Can you please fix them. For readability I would also suggest that you apply some indentation.

Comment: Done. My apologies

Comment: The answer which worked for me is the Promise Queue implementation described by @CertainPerformance here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203406/is-it-ok-to-pass-asynchronous-function-as-websocketws-listerner-node-js-and

Comment: Since I was using the queue as a buffer; I read the first element and then removed it from the array. I therefore change this line of code 'const { sessionData, message } = appendDataQueue.unshift()' to 'const { sessionData, message } = appendDataQueue.shift()'